# Need to change UIScrollView contentSize when portrait xib is adjusted to landscape

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've got a UIViewController with an iPad xib in portrait orientation. When my iPad is in landscape orientation and I put that view controller into my UISplitViewController's detail pane, it gets automatically resized to fit which is great.

However, when I'm configuring my views in -viewDidLoad, the final size of the views is not yet in landscape orientation/size.

The -didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method and the other methods associated with it do not get called when the UIViewController is loaded already in landscape, so when and where am I able to properly set the contentSize of the scroll view and it's contents?

I only want my scroll view to scroll vertically, so I want to make sure that my contentView inside the scrollView is re-fit to the width of the view controller in whatever orientation it is in.

No matter what .frame or .bounds I check, whether it's on my view, my scroll view, or even the detail view controller of my SplitViewController show me what my ACTUAL size is. When in landscape using a UISplitViewController, the left hand side is 320px wide which means the right hand side shouldn't be more than 704px wide, but whenever I check the frames and the bounds of my view and my scrollview, they report as 768px wide which is not correct.

My scrollview is CLEARLY only 704px wide because I can see the scroll indicators correctly.

What am I missing?

Here is my code in -viewDidLoad...

```
CGSize textSize = [self.purchase.textDescription sizeWithFont:self.labelTextDescription.font constrainedToSize:allowedSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect textFrame = self.labelTextDescription.frame;
textFrame.size.height = textSize.height;
self.labelTextDescription.frame = textFrame;

CGRect contentFrame = self.contentView.frame;
contentFrame.size.height += textSize.height;

if (contentFrame.size.width > self.scrollView.frame.size.width) {
    contentFrame.size.width = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
}

self.contentView.frame = contentFrame;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.contentView];
self.scrollView.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you set content size? Is it in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yes, in viewDidLoad and I've added the code.

Comment: Is your UIScrollView's content size really changing when rotating? Isn't the content the same and the same size?

Comment: No, it's not changing and I'm not rotating. My iPad is in landscape before loading the view controller and is in landscape after loading the view controller. However, the xib is in Portrait orientation which means it gets resized automatically. I want to actively keep the size of my content as wide as the scroll view so that it's only scrolling vertically and not horizontally.

Comment: The scrollView's frame and bounds show that it is 768w x 960h during -viewDidLoad, -viewWillAppear and -viewDidAppear even though it is in the detail pane of a UISplitViewController in landscape mode, which means it shouldn't be taller than 768h and it should be thinner than 768w. I can see the scrollbars of the UIScrollView perfectly so I know it has been adjusted to the available width and height, but the frame and bounds do not reflect it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper time to lay out your views and set your scroll view's `contentSize` is during the layout phase of the run loop.  During this phase, UIKit sends the `layoutSubviews` message to any view that has been marked as needing layout and is in a window.  A view is automatically marked as needing layout when various things happen, including when it is first added to a window hierarchy, when it is given a new subview, and when its size changes.  You can also manually mark a view as needing layout by sending it the `setNeedsLayout` message.

By the time a view receives the `layoutSubviews` message, UIKit has already sent `layoutSubviews` to any of the view's ancestors (its superview and up) that needed it, and it has already had its frame adjusted based on its autoresizing mask or autolayout constraints, and its own subviews' frames have already been adjusted based on their autoresizing masks or autolayout constraints.

If `self.view` is already a custom subclass of `UIView`, the best approach is simply to override `layoutSubviews` in that class.  Put your layout code there, and set the scroll view's `contentSize` there.

If you're not using a custom subclass, and you don't want to create one, then you can do the layout in your view controller's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, if you're deployment target is iOS 5.0 or later.  You can probably guess when these messages are sent. :)

During autorotation, all of these messages (`layoutSubviews`, `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) are sent inside the autorotation's animation block, so if you do your layout in one of these methods, you also get the benefit that the changes to your layout will be animated during the autorotation animation.

Comment: -viewDidLayoutSubviews sounds perfect, but I need to support back to iOS4.3. Any suggestion for iOS4? I am not using any custom views.

Comment: I would make a subclass of `UIView` and implement `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: There has got to be a way I can determine the ACTUAL size of my view controller though...

Comment: View controllers don't have sizes.  Views have sizes.  The earliest time you can rely on a view's size to be set correctly is during the layout process, after the view's superview has finished laying out its subviews.  Making a subview of `UIView` is not a big deal.  If you want to be lazy about it, just give the view an `unsafe_unretained` reference back to the view controller, and have its `layoutSubviews` method send a message to the view controller to do the actual layout work.

Comment: Yes, I know it's the view, I mistyped. My point still stands though, there has got to be a way in the view controller life cycle to know what self.view's REAL size is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you don't want to get the view resized when rotating check the autoresize mask. If you built the view in the interface builder then check that it's not changing it's size when the superview does:

[image: Sizing properties of a view]

You can check the current interface orientation of your `UIViewController` with `self.interfaceOrientation`. This might help you if you want to set up you view manually.

Furthermore, if you need to adjust the sizes manually then set the desired frames to your views before (or after) the rotation is performed:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend query the status bar orientation to get the current rotation in `viewDidLoad` I would recommend not relying on auto-resizing for scroll views as it tends to get tricky. Check the status bar the resize proportionally based on that.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`